# What is the purpose of the "active" toggle on fcurve modifiers?

Tags: animation, interface, graph-editor, fcurves

What is the purpose of this toggle?

[image]

What can it be used for?
The [manual page](http://blender.org/manual/editors/graph_editor/fmodifiers.html) doesn't mention anything about it as far as I can see.

Comment: I believe it designates which modifier's properties are being "displayed" on the graph editor canvas.  For an envelope modifier, for instance, if you look carefully at the graph display there are dots for the control points and a stippled line for the envelope limits, of the "active" env mod.

Answer (score 1):

For example, if I click on the noise modifier and it put my mouse over it, it says "F-curve modifier is the one being edited":
[image]

and if I click on the noise modifier and it put my mouse over it, it says "F-curve modifier is the one being edited":
[image]

The graph displayed looks the same whether one or the other is selected.

It basically says which modifier you clicked on

Maybe this could help:
http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_75_3/bpy.types.FModifier.html

Comment: Hm. How is this useful?